# How can I log in to Ubuntu 18.04 without a password? Setting auto login doesn't work

Tags: auto-login

Setting user to automatic login does not permit starting a session on Ubuntu 18.04 without entering the password.

How to fix this?

Comment: Please add the output of `$ cat /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1038751/edit) to your question.