# Password less account asking me to type the password

Tags: unity, login, password

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 with unity DE have an administrator account named as `abhishek`.
Today I created one more password less account named as `public` from GUI.
I set the type of account as 'Standard' instead of 'Administrator' for `public`.
I chose the option as `Login without password` to make a password less account.
After creating the account  successfuly -
I can login without password by just hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, but when I lock my laptop and try to login again then ubuntu login screen is waiting for me to type the password.
As I did not create any password for the user 'public' then why is it asking me to type the password ?
and I also tried to login by pressing Enter key but it is giving me wrong password error.
So I am not able to login again after lock my laptop.
**Help here...**

**EDITS :**
I can login for account 'abhishek' because it is password protected account by giving the correct password at any time.
But my another account 'public' is password less.
So again I am not able to login by pressing 'Enter' key for user 'public', It is prompting me to type the password when i am trying to login after lock my laptop.

Comment: Try your admin password

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I do not want to login by using password. It should login when i press Enter key

Comment: That is to get you into the system so we have an idea what the issue is like, it is not a permanent solution

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I tried your idea but it is not working. Actually 'public' account is like a guest account. so guest don't want to put the password to login they just want to pressing the Enter key for login that's why I created password less 'public' account.

Comment: I have added more information, you can see in Edits section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable guest sessions on Ubuntu 18.04 or later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112349/how-to-enable-guest-sessions-on-ubuntu-18-04-or-later). Using a real Guest session has several advantages over rolling your own version. For example, a Guest session automatically wipes user data after use.

Answer (score 1):

[How to login to Ubuntu 18.04 without a password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102195/how-to-login-to-ubuntu-18-04-without-a-password) Should help with solve the issue.

That is so say, run `sudo passwd -d username` on the command line to prevent this

Do note, as mentioned in the link that this will make authentication difficult in some cases, preventing changes.

Comment: `sudo passwd -d username` tried but did not solve  my problem.

Comment: Small typo in the final line "...this will make authentication DIFFICULT* in some cases". Is that right?

Comment: bah you're right, thank you! @MXMLLN